# Can someone confirm if I am running this generalized linear model in R correctly? Multiple observations in each experimental unit

Tags: r, repeated-measures, nested-data

I'm a grad student and stats beginner just trying to make sure I'm using the right model and using it correctly. I'm using R version 3.5.0. My data look like this:

```
 Nest_ID Treatment  BCI
1    001       NTC 2.18
2    001       NTC 2.54
3    001       NTC 2.23
4    001       NTC 2.33
5    001       NTC 2.37
6    002       NTC 2.10
7    002       NTC 2.61
8    002       NTC 2.51
9    002       NTC 2.18
10   002       NTC 2.40
11   003       NTC 2.15
12   003       NTC 2.29
13   003       NTC 2.45
14   003       NTC 1.80
15   003       NTC 2.15
```

[image: Data]

I have multiple BCI data points for each nest and 5 treatment groups. I want to know if there are differences in BCI between the treatment groups, but each BCI corresponds to individuals from the same nest, and each nest received the same treatment. So at first I took the average BCI from each nest to get a single BCI from each nest and ran an ANOVA on it. This seemed to work fine, but a colleague told me I could use glm and it would account for the fact that I have multiple individuals from a nest that received the same treatment. I tried glm in R, and I don't see how it's accounting for the nest being the lowest statistical unit.

```
GLM <- glm(BCI ~ Treatment, data = Data)
```

When I use this formula, my results come back significant when I don't think they should be. They came back not significant when I just took the average BCI from each group. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a linear [**mixed** model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) as opposed to a generalized linear model. Have a look at the `lme4` package and the `lmer()` function as well as its [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf). Looking at your question I assume you probably want something along those lines: `lmer(BCI ~ Treatment + (1|Nest_ID))`.

Note however that there are also [generalized linear **mixed** models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_mixed_model). Which one to use depends on the nature of your dependent variable.

There is also A LOT of information here on Cross Validated as well as elsewhere on the web on those models and how to interpret and specify them.